# Children props event doesn't hold parent's current state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a state variable which holds components created dynamically, however, when I access the state from a function passed to the child as props, I get the state status from back when it was created. Not so when I log useEffect.

For example: I add 3 children, and in the function logMyChildren I get the state previous to the creation of the last Child element.

First Child `mychildren` is []

Second Child `myChildren` is [{Child with id 0}]

Third Child `myChildren` is [{Child with id 0}, {Child with id 1}]

It gives me the same state with each Child every time I call that function.

Is there a way to get the current state(not a state from the past) regardless of the children?

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [myChildren, setMyChildren] = useState([])

  const addChild = () => {
    let id = myChildren.length + 1
    setMyChildren([
      ...myChildren,
      <Child key={id} id={id} logMyChildren={logMyChildren} />,
    ])
  }

  const logMyChildren = (id) => {
    console.log(id, myChildren)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(myChildren)
  }, [myChildren])

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={addChild}>Add a child</button>
      {myChildren && myChildren.map((child) => child)}
    </>
  )
}

const Child = ({ id, logMyChildren }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <p>A child with id {id}!</p>
      <button onClick={() => logMyChildren(id)}>X</button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Every time `useEffect()` runs, it has the updated state.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for you is that you are creating `logMyChildren` that encloses state variable (in your case `mychildren`).
What you could do is to use `useRef`

Something like this:

```
const stateRef = useRef();
stateRef.current = myChildren;
```

And then in `logMyChildren` you use ref - `stateRef`:

```
console.log(id,stateRef.current);
```

Comment: You are correct, thank you!
However, I needed the state to delete items, I guess I'll try with Redux.

Comment: You could pass down deleteFunction to child component. And also the problem that you are creating array of child components in state, if you would not do that, but instead map some objects to the components  - you had no such problem. Why? - because each time you would pass down "fresh" instance of function to the child component. (In your case, previous instance of function stucks in your state, and never get's updated). So you don't really need Redux here, just not use components in state, or use ref as provided in answer - but actually in this case i would not recommend that